# Recognise when CheckBox_Checked event is fired cause of binding

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I apologize if this has been asked before, but i couldn't find anything helpful.

I have the following class

```
public class NumberOfInterest
{
    public bool HasChanged { get; set; } = false;
    public bool Prop1 { get; set; }
    public bool Prop2 { get; set; }
    ---
}
```

In my user control i have a `DataGrid` that use as item source an `ObservableCollection<NumberOfInterest>`. In this grid i have 2 `CheckBox` columns binded respectively to Prop1 and Prop2

Finally the property `HasChanged` of each `NumberOfInterest` should be set to true when a change from its initial state happes (i.e Prop1 or Prop2 change)

the property HasChanged is used in a Command in the CanExecute event in the following way

```
    public ICommand Save
    {
        get
        {
            save = new RelayCommand(() => SaveChanges(), () => NumbSource.Any(x => x.HasChanged));
            return save;
        }
    }
```

The checkboxes use the Event CheckBox_Checked in the following way

```
    private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox c = sender as CheckBox;
        if (!(c.DataContext is NumberOfInterest n))
            return;
        n.HasChanged = true;
        n.Prop1 = c.IsChecked.Value;
    }
```

and a similar one for Prop2

the problem is that HasChanged is automatically set to true if an element in my item source has any of the 2 Prop1 or Prop2 set to true by default.

I would like to find a way to trigger the `CheckBox_Checked` event only after the user control is in disposition of the user (i.e. the user can iteract with it and everything is loaded).

I tried to set the `Loaded` and `Initialized` to set a local boolean, but those events fire before the item source is actually set

I also tried the Mode = "OneWayToSource" in the checkbox binding, but this prevent the checkbox to be set to the proper state in the first place

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
n.HasChanged = n.Prop1 != c.IsChecked.Value;
n.Prop1 = c.IsChecked.Value;
```

Or:

```
if (c.DataContext is NumberOfInterest n &&
    n.Prop1 != c.IsChecked.Value)
{
    n.HasChanged = true;
    n.Prop1 = c.IsChecked.Value;
}
```

Comment: I correct myself. I was thining it worked at first but then i realized that it's not actually. Cause of the binding  n.Prop1 can't be different from c.IsChecked.Value since the checkbox has the IsCheckedproperty binded to Prop1

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you handle this in the `NumberOfInterest` class instead of handling the `Checked` event in the view?:

```
public class NumberOfInterest
{
    public bool HasChanged { get; set; } = false;

    private bool _prop1;
    public bool Prop1
    {
        get { return _prop1; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _prop1)
            {
                _prop1 = value;
                HasChanged = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _prop2;
    public bool Prop2
    {
        get { return _prop2; }
        set
        { 
            if(value != _prop2)
            {
                _prop2 = value;
                HasChanged = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you set the `Prop1` and `Prop2` *properties* (instead of setting the backing fields) initially, you should also set `HasChanged` to `false` once after you have done this.

A better approach would be to define a custom constructor that performs the initialization:

```
public class NumberOfInterest
{
    public bool HasChanged { get; private set; } = false;

    public NumberOfInterest(bool prop1, bool prop2)
    {
        _prop1 = prop1;
        _prop2 = prop2;
    }

    private bool _prop1;
    public bool Prop1
    {
        get { return _prop1; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _prop1)
            {
                _prop1 = value;
                HasChanged = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _prop2;
    public bool Prop2
    {
        get { return _prop2; }
        set
        { 
            if(value != _prop2)
            {
                _prop2 = value;
                HasChanged = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then also make the setter of `HasChanged` property private.